# How can I put an array in the first index of a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I basically want to put a created array that contains student grades that I took from numericUpDowns into the first index of a 2D array so if I created another student the first one's grades won't be replaced because I would place the second's one in the second index of my 2D array and call this index.

I created and initialized an array that contains 5 indexes with 1 grade for each index and I tried to give my 2D `array[i][0]`(with a for of course) the value of the whole grades array

```
static NumericUpDown[] tabGrades = new NumericUpDown[5];

NumericUpDown[][] tempGrades = new NumericUpDown[tabGrades.Length][];

...

for (int i = 0; i < tempGrades.Length; i++)

{

tempGrades[i][0] = tabGrades[];

break;

}
```

I expected my 2D array to simply take the array as it's first index value but instead it is telling me that I have a syntax error and that a ";" is missing

Comment: On which line you are getting error?

Answer (score 0):

The `tempGrades[i][0]` represents a single element of 2D array which is of type `NumericUpDown` and you are trying to assign an array to that, which is an error. What you need to do is assign the array to `tempGrades[i]` which will represent a row(1D array) in 2D array. So you code would look like `tempGrades[i][0] = tabGrades;`. Your code have other issue like:

1. Array length should be defined while initializing them so

   new NumericUpDown[tabGrades.Length][] this is an error , you have to specify the number of columns also and number of columns should be equal to the length of `tabGrades.Length` as only then you would be `tempGrades[i]` would be able to store `tabGrades`
2. why you are using a loop if you need to run the 1st iteration only. You code should like:

   tempGrades[0][0] = tabGrades;

So you final code should look like:

```
static NumericUpDown[] tabGrades = new NumericUpDown[5];

//Here use whatever length you want instead of 10.
NumericUpDown[][] tempGrades = new NumericUpDown[10][tabGrades.Length]; 

...

tempGrades[0][0] = tabGrades;
```

Comment: I thought that by using a loop with a break It would automatically put a second set of grades into another index without me having to do manually that's why I was using a loop. Thank you a lot!